# Why does my array-based queue fail to display correct values after insertions?

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I tried implementing an array-based queue as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 10

class queue
{
private:
    int rear;
    int front;
    int arr[MAX];
    int data;
    
public:
    queue()
    {
        rear = -1;
        front = -1;
        arr[MAX] = {0};
    }
    
    void insert(int n)
    {
        if (rear == MAX-1)
        {
            std::cout<<"queue is full"<<std::endl;
            return;
        }
        
        if(front == -1)
            front = 0;
            
        arr[rear++] = n;
        
        std::cout<<front<<rear;
        for (int i = front; i<=rear; i++)
        {
            std::cout<<arr[i];
        }
        
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }
    
    int remove()
    {
        if (front == -1)
        {
         std::cout<<"queue is empty"<<std::endl;
         return NULL;
        }
         
        data = arr[front];
        
        if (front == rear)
          front = rear = -1;   
        else
          front++;
          
        return data;        
    }

};

int main()
{
    queue q;
    
    q.insert(1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to insert something into the queue, it does not print the value inserted using the loop:

```cpp
std::cout<<front<<rear;
for (int i = front; i<=rear; i++)
{
    std::cout<<arr[i];
}

std::cout<<'\n';
```

I just printed out the `front` and `rear` values before entering the loop, and it says that `front` equals 1, and `rear` equals 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is that in the insert function, you do:

```
arr[rear++] = n;
```

but you should do this instead:

```cpp
rear++;
arr[rear] = n;
```

The reason is that by incrementing using the postfix operator (`rear++`), the value of rear is incremented, but the value of the expression is the original value of rear. So, the first time you do it, `arr[rear++]` evaluates to `arr[-1]`, which is undefined behavior.

Another enhancement would be to make `data` a local variable of the `remove` function instead of making it a private field, there's no advantage in doing it.